# FB Connect - Login button not clickable

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

On my site the fb connect login button suddenly became unclickable, I have no idea what I did

http://www.belginfish.com/mp3/

(top right)

If anyone has any idea that would be excellent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A div element with class="search_area" is lying on top if your facebook button. Its transparent so the fb button is still visible. Rectify your html/css and fb button will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. We were upgrading from FB Login v1.0 to v2.1. The old version was relatively simple to skin by just swapping in your own background image, and hiding the original image, like:

```
background: url(/ui/img/fb-login-small.png) no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
```

Unfortunately in v2.1 this same code will hose you. You'll end up seeing your custom image, but it won't be clickable. Furthermore, the real button does load without any errors, and is promptly shuttled off -9999px offscreen. That can be pretty confusing.

The solution is to just get rid of the image replacement (get rid of the 2 CSS lines above) so the real FB login button can show through.